# Model is not iterable in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm getting this error when I click on a button.
When I click the button I'm calling a function named **apply**.
So first of all, I've two models, `JobServices` and `MissionEffectuee`, the table `MissionEffectuee` is normally filled with content of `JobServices`.

The 2 models:

```
class JobServices(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #create_user
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="nom du service")
    hour = models.IntegerField(default="Heures")
    amount = models.FloatField(default="Cout")
    service_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, default="annonce")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class MissionEffectuee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey(JobServices, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rcd_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Here is the views methods

```
def apply(request, my_id):
    task_applied = JobServices.objects.get(id=my_id)
    task_done, failed = MissionEffectuee.objects.get_or_create(id=my_id)
    if failed:
        for c in task_applied:
            task_done.service = c.service_name
            task_done.user = c.user
            print("it's saved")
        task_done.save()
    else:
        print("Element is already there")
        return redirect('../taches')

    context = {'task_done': task_done}
    return render(request, 'task_apply.html', context)
```

What I want is whenever I click on the button, `service_name` of the model `Jobservices` and `user` of the model `User` to be saved in the table `MissionEffectuee` in the attributes `service` and `user` respectively, but as for now, in the table these two columns are filled with hypen (-). But the `rcd_date` attributes normally filled as I want.

I think the problem is with the `foreignkeys`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `get` on your `JobServices` model which will return 1 instance of that model.

So you need to just use that 1 instance, like this;

```
task_applied = JobServices.objects.get(id=my_id)
task_done, failed = MissionEffectuee.objects.get_or_create(id=my_id)
if failed:
    task_done.service = task_applied  # This must be a `JobServices` instance, not the name
    task_done.user = task_applied.user
    print("it's saved")
    task_done.save()
```

If you used `JobServices.objects.filter()` then it'd return a queryset of objects from that table and you could iterate over that like you do with `for c in task_applied`.

Comment: When I do as you said it, then I will get the following error: MissionEffectuee.service" must be a "JobServices" instance

Comment: @Sadick oh of course. I didn't read your code in enough detail. Will update my answer. You need to set it as the instance you get from the database, not the `service_name` attribute.

Comment: How can I get service_name? As for now the user is gotten but for the service attribute is filled with something like JobServices object (2), I need just the service_name which is in JobServices object (2)

Comment: `task_done.service.service_name` would give you the service name. You probably shouldn't change the model to a `CharField` from the `FK` because it's more limiting in it's functionality.